# Как считывать, что пользователь нажал на url button в InlineKeyboard? Telegraf

Tags: javascript, telegraf

У меня есть InlineKeyboard с url button, как я могу считывать, что пользователь нажал на эту кнопку? Использую node.js , telegraf

Comment: Понял, сделать не возможно.

Comment: используй прокси-ссылки в которые зашиваешь все нужные данные, считаешь переходы по ним и редиректишь на целевой URL

Comment: @МихаилРебров благодарю.